# Possible to create a hook for failing JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit

We have a unit tests parent Base class, and a set of unit tests extending the base class. I want every failing test to call a particular method. Is is possible to create a "hook" or something somewhere, i.e. passing tests do not call this method, but failing tests do at the end of execution.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? If you explain your overall goal there may be a better solution we can suggest.

Comment: oh sure, I want to take a full page screenshot at the end when a test fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at TestWatcher class.
Create your own class extending TestWatcher, override the failed(Throwable e, Description description) method and add a rule to your test.

```
public class MyWatcher extends TestWatcher {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
         callMyMethod();
    }
}
```

Your test :

```
public class MyTest {
      @Rule 
      public MyWatcher rule = new MyWatcher ();

      @Test
      public myTest(){...}
}
```

There also useful method in TestWatcher, like starting() and finished()

Comment: Does anything else need to extend this MyWatcher class, or is it just enough if you create the MyWatcher class like you described in my custom project? Also, I didn't quite understand what role the @Rule tag plays here

Comment: Should't it be `@Rule MyWatcher rule = new MyWatcher();`?

Comment: Oh, if atamanroman is right, then I understand. Can the @Rule be added in the parent test base class, or does every individual test need to have it?

Comment: Have a look here: http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html